# Git add all unstaged/untracked files with a single command

Tags: git

pardon the newbie question. I'm looking for a quick but safe option to add all unstaged/untracked files (returned by "git status") with one command. Is it safe to use from the project root:

```
git add *
```

Any drawback?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` is a wildcard expanded by the shell. It won't match "hidden" files (those whose names start with `.`) and it will fail if there are too many files in the current directory to fit on the command line.

A solution without these drawbacks is:

```
git add .
```

This works because git adds the contents of directories recursively, so telling it to add `.` (the current directory) adds everything.

Another difference relates to `.gitignore` patterns. If you have a file in the current directory that matches a pattern in `.gitignore`, then `git add .` will just silently ignore it. But shell wildcards don't know about `.gitignore`, so when you do `git add *`, the ignored file will be explicitly added to the `git add` command, which causes `git add` to fail with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git add .` instead of `git add *`.

`git add .` will add all local untrack files to the staging area, and will filter according to .gitignore.

But `git add *` will ignore `.gitignore` to add every files.